# Reducing a page of content to a short paragraph

Tags: text-mining

I remember years ago, Yahoo detailed how they were able to reduce a webpage down to a short paragrah of text succently summarising the content in sentences, as opposed to a list of keywords. What is this called? Are there any open / free code to do this?

Comment: It's called [text summarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into TextRank algorithm, here is the paper [paper](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mihalcea/papers/mihalcea.emnlp04.pdf). You can find a neat python implementation here [textrank implementation](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/summanlp/textrank&ved=0ahUKEwiSpsaXl5LRAhWIn5QKHW0CBlIQFgglMAE&usg=AFQjCNGjD49GTQDcAMWDEDAuhV-KiZEI4Q&sig2=MqCu22mjcHy89ob9sZNIYg) If I am not wrong gensim also offers an implementation.